# How to show RSS feeds from my Wordpress blog in my CakePHP website?

Tags: wordpress, cakephp, rss, feed

How i can show the RSS Feed from my WordPress blog into my CakePHP website?

I need the result to be a list where i can use the html code:

```
<ul>
<li>feed item 1</li>
<li>feed item 2</li>
...
<li>feed item n</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Feed [this example code](http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2009/06/cakephp-parsing-rss-feed-in-simple-steps.html) your WordPress RSS URL and you'll be in business.

Comment: I needed it to be compatible with UTF-8 characters. 

I just had to tweak it using the php function utf8_decode().


Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If its your own blog and you have access to the database of your blog, you could use this component to get your posts: https://github.com/atomtigerzoo/cakePHP-Wordpress-Component

It has much more options for displaying posts, thumbnails urls etc.